# Flutter number keyboard with 'Done' for iOS

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, keyboard

```
TextFormField(
 key: Key(keyValue),
 initialValue: valueBuilder,
 onSaved: (text) {
        
 },
 inputFormatters: [inputFormatters],
 keyboardType: TextInputType.number,)
```

I also tried

keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(signed: true, decimal: true)

but it was not working too.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add following line and it will work for you

```
TextFormField(
    .....
    keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(signed: true, decimal: true), // OR keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
    textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
)
```